# How do I set up a Firebase DB for Topeka, the Polymer sample quiz app?

Tags: firebase, polymer

I am trying to customize the Topeka quiz app by the Polymer team for a class, but do not know how to set up a Firebase DB for the leaderboard. I don't have the authentication needed to view the Polymer team's DB. I have changed topeka-leaderboard.html and topeka-datasource.html to reference my DB. The quiz app is hosted at http://adueppen.github.io/quiz and the DB is at https://incandescent-fire-8717.firebaseio.com.

Answer (score 0):

This question is long overdue, but here is my answer.

1. Modify Firebase location URLs in **components/topeka-elements/topeka-datasource.html** and **components/topeka-elements/topeka-leaderboard.html** (you've already done this)

   - change `'https://polymer-topeka.firebaseio.com/users/'` to `'https://<your-firebase>.firebaseio.com/users/'`
2. Enable anonymous login, which is the type of login the Polymer team has chosen to use for Topeka.

   - Go to your Firebase Dashboard > Login & Auth > Anonymous. Check where it says "Enable Anonymous User Authentication".
3. Set security rules.

   - Go to your Firebase Dashboard > Security & Rules. Paste in the following and click "Save Rules":

   ```
   {
     "rules": {
       ".read": true,
       "users": {
         "$userId": {
           ".write": "auth.uid === $userId",
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   - The above rules allow all users to read data (this is necessary for updating Leaderboard); allow the logged in user to write only his own data. [A quick tutorial on Firebase Security API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IGlzbmnAlRQ)

Following the above steps should allow you to replicate Topeka's Firebase integration.

Comment: I followed the instructions here, but I'm still not getting anything in the DB. Sorry for the late response, I had to finish up school.

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/yA6I5ut.jpg) is what the structure of my database looks like.